# ngx-responsive - Can't bind to 'responsive-window' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: html, angular, npm

I am using the npm ngx-responsive.

In my app.module I have imported the module (after the npm install)

```
import { ResponsiveModule } from 'ngx-responsive'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      ResponsiveModule.forRoot()
    ],
})
```

In my HTML I a have a sample code for rendering a

```
<div [responsive-window]="'parent'">
     <p *responsive="{ sizes:{  window: 'parent', min:100, max:600} }"></p>
 </div>
```

I still get a error that it can't be bind because it's not a property of div.
And the same problem with the paragraph element

Can someone help me...

Comment: Your NgModule declaration has no component declared. If you only posted part of the module, then consider making a reproducible example, for example on [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)

Answer (score 0):

In app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { ResponsiveModule } from 'ngx-responsive'
const config = {
breakPoints: {
    xs: {max: 600},
    sm: {min: 601, max: 959},
    md: {min: 960, max: 1279},
    lg: {min: 1280, max: 1919},
    xl: {min: 1920}
},
debounceTime: 100
};

@NgModule({
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  ResponsiveModule.forRoot(config)
],
declarations: [
  AppComponent
],
providers:[]
})
```

HTML

```
<div [responsive-window]="'parent'">
    <p *responsive="{ sizes:{  window: 'parent', min:900, max:1400} }"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is if you want to use custom breakpoints. This can be added later. but this is not the fix for me.

Comment: I had to declare the module inside the the module of the component in stead of the app module. Which is weird the app (and I have a shrared module which is shared over the whole application) is used for the entire application. still I had to add the responsive module to the closest .module